# How to compare two std::any?

Tags: c++, c++17

There's no operator== for std::any

Am I missing something obvious or do I need to actually earn my living?

Is there some simple way to provide the operator?

https://godbolt.org/z/rdoWrcnTs

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <any>

int main()
{
    auto str1 = std::make_any<std::string> ("Hello");
    auto str2 = std::make_any<std::string> ("World");
    
    if(str1 == str2) std::cout << "same"; // error
}
```

Comment: A related detail: `std::any` can hold types that don't support comparison operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no direct way to compare two objects of `std::any` because the underlying types may not be the same. If you know they're the same, you can write:

```
if(std::any_cast<std::string>(str1) == std::any_cast<std::string>(str2)) 
  // ...
```

Comment: I thought as much, I do have a typeid number for the thing, so I can make a thing where comparison operators are registered, paired with the typeid. Then I just find the correct one and apply.

Comment: @0xbaadf00d Yes, I guess that would work. You need to be careful though. In case the types are different, or the types are the same but not comparable, you have to decide what to do. Returning `false` could be misleading as that's what you would return if the values are not equal.

Comment: It throws an exception now. The one provided by std::any_cast, like yours does.

Comment: In case you know they will always be a string, you could also do something like 
`if (str1.compare(str2) != 0){ std::cout << str1 << " is not " << str2 << '\n';}`

Comment: Could you compare the types and then use a hash? (For example, if you didn't know the types were `std::string`?

Comment: @user14717 Yes, I suppose you could check the types using `type` and then do a hash, but once you have the types, you could just `any_cast` and use `==` directly (assuming that operation is supported. If not, you could compare the hashes instead)

Comment: Well, the types have to be known at compile-time to get them into the template argument. If you learn the type at runtime then I suppose you have to hash.

Comment: I actually optimized this, because sometimes I know one or both of the types that the any contains. I can shorten the hash lookup or outright remove it at times. Learn my lesson, don't use std::function for the compare, it's VERY slow. Just use a raw function ptr and it's fast.